# undefined variable when the variable exists laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when i click delete all selected its saying undefined variable however when i check the database the post gets deleted and when i  refresh the page the post gets removed from the page. I don't understand why its bringing an error when its working.[image]

### blade

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.5/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Delete All Selected
    
        
            
           
            post Name
            post Details
            Action
        
        
     
       
            @foreach($posts as $key => $post)
                id}}">
                    id}}">
                    {{ ++$key }}
                    {{ $post->about }}
                    {{ $post->image }}
                    
                         id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                           data-tr="tr_{{$post->id}}"
                           data-toggle="confirmation"
                           data-btn-ok-label="Delete" data-btn-ok-icon="fa fa-remove"
                           data-btn-ok-class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                           data-btn-cancel-label="Cancel"
                           data-btn-cancel-icon="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"
                           data-btn-cancel-class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
                           data-title="Are you sure you want to delete ?"
                           data-placement="left" data-singleton="true">
                            Delete
                        
                    
                
            @endforeach

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#master').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))
         {
            $(".sub_chk").prop('checked', true);
         } else {
            $(".sub_chk").prop('checked',false);
         }
        });


        $('.delete_all').on('click', function(e) {


            var allVals = [];
            $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {
                allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
            });


            if(allVals.length <=0)
            {
                alert("Please select row.");
            }  else {


                var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?");
                if(check == true){


                    var join_selected_values = allVals.join(",");


                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).data('url'),
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data['success']) {
                                $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {
                                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                                });
                                alert(data['success']);
                            } else if (data['error']) {
                                alert(data['error']);
                            } else {
                                alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert(data.responseText);
                        }
                    });


                  $.each(allVals, function( index, value ) {
                      $('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + value + "']").remove();
                  });
                }
            }
        });


        $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
            rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
            onConfirm: function (event, element) {
                element.trigger('confirm');
            }
        });


        $(document).on('confirm', function (e) {
            var ele = e.target;
            e.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({
                url: ele.href,
                type: 'DELETE',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['success']) {
                        $("#" + data['tr']).slideUp("slow");
                        alert(data['success']);
                    } else if (data['error']) {
                        alert(data['error']);
                    } else {
                        alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            });


            return false;
        });
    });
</script>


</html>
```

```

### controller

```
public function showem(Post $post)
{
  $posts = Post::get();
  


  return view('users.registered', compact('posts'));
}
public function deleteAll(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
    $deleted = Post::whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->delete();
    return view('users.registered');
}
```

Comment: Which variable is undefined here?

Comment: sorry was still editing the question. $post variable

Comment: Please show the controller code as well.

Comment: @aynber controller added

Comment: @STA the image of the error has been added in the post

Comment: What the output of `dd($posts);`?

Answer (score 0):

After review your full question again and again, I found that you have got this error on detele method.  
You need to send `posts` variable also on delete method :

```
public function showem(Post $post)
{
    $posts = Post::get();
    return view('users.registered', compact('posts'));
}

public function deleteAll(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
    $deleted = Post::whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->delete();
    $posts = Post::get();
    return view('users.registered', compact('posts')); // here send the posts variable
}
```